# How to generate a machine readable yaml specification of an existing API written in flask-restplus?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I have a simple API written with the help of flask-restplus:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)                  #  Create a Flask WSGI application
api = Api(app)                         #  Create a Flask-RESTPlus API

@api.route('/hello')                   #  Create a URL route to this resource
class HelloWorld(Resource):            #  Create a RESTful resource
    def get(self):                     #  Create GET endpoint
        return {'hello': 'world'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I navigate to `loacalhost:5000/` in the browser I get a basic Swagger documentation, but I can't find where do I get a machine readable plain yaml representation of the API, should't it be also generated automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not find any information around "Swagger Yaml documentation generation" in the official [flask-restplus docs](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). So, I decided to examine the source code and found that the `Swagger` class implements the Swagger documentation generation for the API instance.

The `Swagger` class in the flask-restplus source-code is the Swagger documentation wrapper for an API instance. All methods in this class suggest that the API data is serialized as a JSON dictionary. For instance, consider the `as_dict()` function of this class which serializes the full Swagger specification as a serializable dict. Take a look at the docstring for this function:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from flask_restplus.api import Swagger

app = Flask(__name__)                  
api = Api(app)

swag = Swagger(api)
print(swag.as_dict.__doc__) 

#Output:
Output the specification as a serializable ``dict``.

    :returns: the full Swagger specification in a serializable format
    :rtype: dict
```

I maybe wrong but the source code suggests that the API documentation is only returned as `JSON` which is available at `http://localhost:5000/swagger.json` by default. I could not find anything for YAML.

But there is a workaround to generate YAML documentation for your API. I used the `json` and `yaml` libraries to dump the json response from `/swagger.json` into YAML and save it to `yamldoc.yml`. You can invoke this by going to `http://localhost:5000/swagger.yml`. The full code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from flask_restplus.api import Swagger
import requests
import json, yaml

app = Flask(__name__)                  #  Create a Flask WSGI application
api = Api(app)                         #  Create a Flask-RESTPlus API

@api.route('/hello')                   #  Create a URL route to this resource
class HelloWorld(Resource):            #  Create a RESTful resource
    def get(self):                  
        return {'hello': 'world'}

@api.route('/swagger.yml')
class HelloWorld(Resource):    
    def get(self):
       url = 'http://localhost:5000/swagger.json'       
       resp = requests.get(url)
       data = json.loads(resp.content)    
       with open('yamldoc.yml', 'w') as yamlf:
           yaml.dump(data, yamlf, allow_unicode=True)
       return {"message":"Yaml document generated!"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help! You may accept as answer if it has worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

From @amanb answer I made my api return a yaml file, without making any requests. 
According to documentation of flask restplus (or, the most recent fork, [flask restx](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) it is possible to [export the Swagger specififcations corresponding to your API](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/export.html) using:

```
from flask import json

from myapp import api

print(json.dumps(api.__schema__))
```

So, instead of using `requests` I preferred to use `api.__schema__`.

As my goal is to provide the file for download at the time of the request, it is necessary to use the `send_file` function of `Flask`. In addition, this file can be later deleted from the directory so we can use the `after_this_request` decorator of `Flask` to invoke the annotated function that will delete the file. The full code:

```
import os
import json
import yaml

from flask import Flask, after_this_request, send_file, safe_join, abort
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from flask_restplus.api import Swagger


app = Flask(__name__)                  #  Create a Flask WSGI application
api = Api(app)                         #  Create a Flask-RESTPlus API

@api.route('/hello')                   #  Create a URL route to this resource
class HelloWorld(Resource):            #  Create a RESTful resource
    def get(self):                  
        return {'hello': 'world'}

@api.route('/swagger.yml')
class HelloWorld(Resource):    
    def get(self):
       data = json.loads(json.dumps(api.__schema__))
       with open('yamldoc.yml', 'w') as yamlf:
           yaml.dump(data, yamlf, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False)
           file = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
           try:
               @after_this_request
               def remove_file(resp):
                   try:
                       os.remove(safe_join(file, 'yamldoc.yml'))
                   except Exception as error:
                       log.error("Error removing or closing downloaded file handle", error)
                   return resp

               return send_file(safe_join(file, 'yamldoc.yml'), as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='yamldoc.yml', mimetype='application/x-yaml')
           except FileExistsError:
               abort(404)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```